# Active admin nested form not working Error: too many arguments for format string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, nested-attributes, has-one

Following is my code block of state Model, SatatImage Model and Active Admin Code. In active admin when I try to create a new record or Edit a --record that time I show an error on production server. but works on my localhost in development mode,
---------Error---------------------------

### too many arguments for format string

app/admin/state.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in '

I am using Ruby 1.9, Rails 3,2, activeadmin (0.6.0)

```
======State Model===============
class State < ActiveRecord::Base

   attr_accessible :name, :code
   validates :code, :uniqueness => true
   has_one :state_image, :dependent => :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :state_image, :allow_destroy => true
   .......
 end

==============StatImage Model=============

class StateImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :state_id, :stateimage, :image_name

  belongs_to :state
  mount_uploader :stateimage, StateUploader
end


=======Active Admin part=================

ActiveAdmin.register State do
 .....

 form(html:{multipart:true}) do |f|

   f.inputs "State Form" do
     f.input :name, required:true
     f.input :code, required:true
   end

  #line-49#  
 f.inputs "StateImage", for:[:state_image, f.object.state_image ||   StateImage.new] do |p|
     p.input :stateimage, :as => :file, :label => "Image" 

   end
   f.buttons :submit
 end

end
```

Comment: What is app/admin/state.rb on line 49?

Comment: Provide some more lines of the stacktrace

Comment: f.inputs "StateImage", for:[:state_image, f.object.state_image ||   StateImage.new] do |p|
 this line is 49 no line

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
 f.semantic_fields_for
```

And Formtastic requires you to wrap ALL inputs in an "inputs" block. So this should be:

```
f.inputs 'State Image' do
    f.semantic_fields_for :state_image, (f.object.state_image || StateImage.new) do |p|
      p.inputs do
          p.input :stateimage, :as => :file, :label => "Image"
          p.input :_destroy, :as => :boolean, :required => false, :label => 'Remove image'
     end
   end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

> form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|

Also upgrade you activeadmin version to 0.6.6

Comment: Still show same error : too many arguments for format string
1: insert_tag renderer_for(:new)
app/admin/state.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'